# Switch between two or more edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext

Suppose I have two or more `EditText`view  in my layout and at run time by mistake I selected 2nd view and filled it with text; now I want to go to previous `EditText` view and on touch gain it's focus to write some text inside it.

But I am unable to do this. I can't gain focus of view and write it on click that particular view.

See the code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/wall">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="@string/Title" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="45dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="@string/program" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CalDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/body"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RunProgram"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/Calculate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Calculate"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Calculate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RunProgram"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/Save"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RunProgram"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/body"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/Run" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so basically u are not able to enter text in first edittext after entering text in second one??

Comment: why are you using focusable= true in both of edittext. it ll take in one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this...

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="program"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CalDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/save"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Calculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/RunProgram"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Run"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout`. Because it seems like your `EditText` are overlapping each other (causing the problem in getting focus), or at least add some respective aligning to them.

For example, add the following to your second `EditText`:

```
android:layout_below="@id/title"
```